# If $\omega\underline{\in}\alpha$ and $\alpha^2\underline{\in}\beta$ then $\alpha+\beta=\beta$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I'm trying to prove that if $\omega\underline{\in}\alpha$ and $\alpha^2\underline{\in}\beta$ then $\alpha+\beta=\beta$ where $\alpha,\beta$ are ordinals. I am using transfinite induction for ordinals and inducting on $\beta$. I have already proved $\omega\underline{\in}\alpha$ implies $1+\alpha=\alpha$ (*) so this can be assumed.

I can prove the result assuming $\beta$ is a successor ordinal but I am having difficulty assuming $\beta$ is a limit ordinal. My induction hypothesis is $\zeta\in\beta\rightarrow(\omega\underline{\in}\alpha\land\alpha^2\underline{\in}\zeta\rightarrow\alpha+\zeta=\zeta).$  I am assuming $\omega\underline{\in}\alpha$ and $\alpha^2\underline{\in}\beta$.

So far for the limit ordinal case (which does notactually use the fact that $\beta$ is a limit ordinal) I have proceeded as follows.
As $\alpha^2\underline{\in}\beta$ we know ${\alpha+\alpha}^2\underline{\in}\alpha+\beta$ and so, $\alpha\cdot(\phi^++\alpha)\underline{\in}\alpha+\beta$ and so by *, $\alpha^2\underline{\in}\alpha+\beta $ (**).
Now assume $\alpha+\beta\in\beta$. Then using ** and the induction hypothesis, $\alpha+(\alpha+\beta)=\alpha+\beta $ and so by left cancellation, $\alpha+\beta=\beta$, a contradiction.
Now assume $\beta\in\alpha+\beta$. Then as $\alpha^2\underline{\in}\beta$, either $\alpha^2=\beta$ or $\alpha^2\in\beta$. If $ \alpha^2=\beta$ then $\alpha+\alpha^2=\alpha+\beta$ and so $\alpha\cdot(\phi^++\alpha)=\alpha+\beta$ or, using *, $\alpha^2=\alpha+\beta$ so $\beta\in\alpha^2=\beta$, a contradiction.
The only other case is if  $\beta\in\alpha+\beta$ and $\alpha^2\in\beta$, from which I cannot generate a contradiction. If anyone can help, much appreciated. Alternatively, if there is a better approach to the problem, or if I have made any mistakes, that will help as well!

Comment: By $w$, do you mean $\omega$?

Comment: Ah, yes, didn’t realise there was a different font to be used.

Comment: It's not a different font. It's a different letter. One is the English letter "double you" and the other is the Greek letter "omega".

Comment: OK, fixed up the omegas :)

Comment: "$\underline{\in}$", Really? What is wrong with just saying $\le$? By the only sensible interpretation of "$\underline{\in}$" I see, it means the exact same thing. Further, Von Neumann's construction under which "$\alpha < \beta$" if and only if "$\alpha \in \beta$" is not even a necessary part of the theory of ordinal numbers. It is very nice, but not necessary. Okay, I know - this is not your notation, you are just using what your class uses, and that is okay. But I felt the need to rant against this confusing and completely unneeded notation.

Comment: Hi Paul, No, I am not just using what my class uses. I don't attend any classes as I am self studying because I enjoy studying maths :). I am using many texts, but the ones that I have found the best are "Enderton, Elements of Set theory"and "Cunningham, Set Theory a first course", both of which use this notation exclusively. I don't find it confusing at all, and after disliking it initially, I now prefer it. From the texts I have used, the $\underline{\in}$ notation arises naturally from the definitions of ordinal numbers. Anyway, anyone got any comments on the solving the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario it might be more clear how to prove the stronger-looking claim you get by only assuming $\alpha\omega\underline\in\beta$. Since ordinal multiplication is monotonic in the right argument (lemma 3.14 in Schlöder's set of notes ["Ordinal Arithmetic"](https://jjsch.github.io/output/oa.pdf)), we have $\alpha\omega\underline\in\alpha\alpha$, so this modified version will imply your original question. This is an attempted proof without transfinite induction.

Assume $\omega\underline\in\alpha$ and $\alpha\omega\underline\in\beta$. Then there must be some $\eta$ such that $\alpha\omega+\eta=\beta$, this isn't supposed to be an application of Euclidean division, instead $\eta$ is supposed to be like "$-\alpha\omega+\beta$" and is well-defined because ["Ordinal Subtraction when Possible is Unique"](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Ordinal_Subtraction_when_Possible_is_Unique). Now we've decomposed $\beta$ into $\alpha\omega$ and an extra part $\eta$, the $\eta$ doesn't matter much other than to get the extra part after the initial $\alpha\omega$ out of the way. Then, $\alpha\omega+\eta=\alpha(1+\omega)+\eta$, which equals $\alpha+\alpha\omega+\eta$ by [left distributivity](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Ordinal_Multiplication_is_Left_Distributive), which then is $\alpha+(\alpha\omega+\eta)$ by [associativity of addition](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Ordinal_Addition_is_Associative), and this whole thing is equal to $\alpha+\beta$ which is what we wanted. In other words, we appended another copy of $\alpha$ to the left of the $\alpha\omega$ part and the ordering still remained isomorphic to $\beta$.

Comment: Hi C7X, Is there a reason that you’ve called this an attempt, as it looks right to me. Do you have any doubts about any of the steps?  Once we have “Ordinal Subtraction”, which itself is proved by transfinite ordinal induction, it seems to fall out pretty easily. PS apologies for the delay. I’ve been on holidays the last week :)

Comment: PS Thanks very much for your response and help!

Comment: @Porky Thank you! Since your approach was different I was not sure I was giving an answer you would like, so I labeled this my own attempt. Also, it diverges from the induction on $\beta$, if that assumption was a requirement for an exercise or assignment, I was not sure if this answer would be useful.